# Ruby Mp3Info not closing properly before moving

Tags: ruby, file, exception, filesystems, mp3

I'm new to Ruby, so forgive my ignorance with the language.

I wrote a simple application to help me organize my music. This application simply reads a folder, gets all of the MP3 files:

If the Title tag contains a (feat. someArtist) then move it to the Artist tag

and then just split the '(feat....)' stuff and store it separately so that I can use that to organize my music in separate folders by Genre/Artist/Album/songFile

This is just my way of parsing all of my music and keeping folders to a minimum by stripping the 'features' this way "Eminem (feat. Rihanna)" won't have a separate folder and instead will just be placed within the "Eminem" folder.

Here's my source:

```
require "pry"
require "mp3info"
require "fileutils"

PATH = "C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MusicFolder"

$mediaFiles = []
$errorRenaming = []
$errorMoving = []

class MusicFile
  attr_accessor :fileName, :fullyQualifiedPath, :soloArtist
  def initialize(fileName, fullyQualifiedPath)
    @fileName = fileName
    @fullyQualifiedPath = fullyQualifiedPath
  end
end

def printFiles
  parseFileIntoArray
  $mediaFiles.each do |item|
    puts item.fullyQualifiedPath #prints all fileName's within the array
  end
end


private
def parseFileIntoArray
  fullyQualifiedFileNames = Dir.glob("#{PATH}/**/*.mp3").select { |fn| File.file?(fn) }

  fullyQualifiedFileNames.each do |files|
    $mediaFiles << MusicFile.new(files.split('/')[-1], files) #Store fully qualified filename inside of Array
  end
end

#take all files, read artist
#remove (feat) from it and store artist

def moveFilesIntoFolders
  $mediaFiles.each do |file|
    mp3File = Mp3Info.open(file.fullyQualifiedPath) #WHOLE PROGRAM DIES RIGHT HERE
    destinationFolder = "#{PATH}/CONVERTED/#{mp3File.tag.genre_s}/#{file.soloArtist}/#{mp3File.tag.album}"
    unless File.directory?(destinationFolder)
      begin
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(destinationFolder)
      rescue => exception
        puts exception.backtrace
        puts "Error creating directory #{destinationFolder}"
      end
    end
    File.open(file.fullyQualifiedPath, "r") do |itemToMove|
      begin
        FileUtils.cp(itemToMove, destinationFolder)
      rescue => exception
        puts exception.backtrace
        $errorMoving << file.fileName
        $errorMoving.each do |error|
          puts "errors moving: #{error}"
        end
      end
    end
    mp3File.close
  end
  puts "leaving moveFilesIntoFolders"
end

def getFeatAndParse
  $mediaFiles.each do |item|
    mp3File = Mp3Info.open(item.fullyQualifiedPath)
    item.soloArtist = mp3File.tag.artist
      if mp3File.tag.title.include?("(feat")
         theIndex = mp3File.tag.title.index("(feat")
         substring = mp3File.tag.title[theIndex..-1]
      elsif mp3File.tag.artist.include?("(feat")
          theIndex = mp3File.tag.artist.index("(feat")
          substring = mp3File.tag.artist[theIndex..-1]
      end
      mp3File.tag.artist.slice! substring
      mp3File.tag.artist = mp3File.tag.artist.split.join(" ")
      item.soloArtist = mp3File.tag.artist
      mp3File.tag.artist = "#{mp3File.tag.artist} #{substring}"
      mp3File.close
      begin
        File.rename(item.fullyQualifiedPath, "#{PATH}/#{mp3File.tag.title} - #{item.soloArtist} - #{mp3File.tag.album}.mp3")
      rescue => exception
        puts exception.backtrace
        $errorRenaming << item.fileName
        $errorRenaming.each do |error|
          puts "errors renaming: #{error}"
        end
      end
  end
end


parseFileIntoArray
getFeatAndParse
moveFilesIntoFolders
```

Inside my "moveFilesIntoFolders" method, it throws an exception on the MP3File.open statement.
The exception is as follows:

```
D:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-mp3info-0.8.10/lib/mp3
info.rb:244:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MusicFolder/test.mp3 (Errno::ENOENT)
        from D:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-mp3info-0
.8.10/lib/mp3info.rb:244:in `new'
        from D:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-mp3info-0
.8.10/lib/mp3info.rb:244:in `reload'
        from D:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-mp3info-0
.8.10/lib/mp3info.rb:230:in `initialize'
        from D:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-mp3info-0
.8.10/lib/mp3info.rb:300:in `new'
        from D:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-mp3info-0
.8.10/lib/mp3info.rb:300:in `open'
        from ./main.rb:59:in `block in moveFilesIntoFolders'
        from ./main.rb:58:in `each'
        from ./main.rb:58:in `moveFilesIntoFolders'
        from ./main.rb:124:in `<main>'
```

At the end of this, all of the files are renamed correct. Only moving them into folders has failed. My thought is that the Operating System hasn't fully completed renaming all of the files yet or reflected that, and so then trying to move the files is causing an exception because it's being read by another source already?

If I re-run the application after the exception **only** running "moveIntoFolders" method, then it works perfectly. It's just the fact that I'm doing the renaming and then immediately doing the moving in a separate method that's causing the exception.
So is there a way to make Ruby wait for the process to finish completely or anything? I even tried doing a 'sleep' command and that didn't work..

I just don't know enough about the language or have experience debugging it even using Pry to help me figure out the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by making sure the asynchronous stream was not open at the time of the move.

I just kept the data it was pulling, in the object itself

```
def moveFilesIntoFolders
  $mediaFiles.each do |file|
    destinationFolder = "#{PATH}/CONVERTED/#{file.genre}/#{file.soloArtist}/#{file.album}"
    unless File.directory?(destinationFolder)
      begin
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(destinationFolder)
      rescue => exception
        puts exception.backtrace
        puts "Error creating directory #{destinationFolder}"
      end
    end
    File.open(file.fullyQualifiedPath, "r") do |itemToMove|
      begin
        FileUtils.cp(itemToMove, destinationFolder)
      rescue => exception
        puts exception.backtrace
        $errorMoving << file.fileName
        $errorMoving.each do |error|
          puts "errors moving: #{error}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```